# How to disable "Look Up" context menu across macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, spotlight, shortcut-menu

No matter which browser you use, there's always a Look Up menu when right-clicking any text inside the web browser.

I have disabled Lookup/Spotlight suggestions on right-clicking, via System Preferences, but on right-clicking any text in any browser, the Look Up menu still shows up with dictionary suggestions.

Is there anyway to disable this from the core. I have gone through other AskDifferent posts similar to mine, but none of them seems to have an answer!

Comment: For Chrome they add the `Lookup` menu item themselves, it's not provided by the OS. https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:chrome/browser/ui/cocoa/renderer_context_menu/render_view_context_menu_mac.mm;l=105-126;drc=da78f55f373f3870ea66fa7ec295cd1934e5f93f

If you want to get rid of it in Chrome or elsewhere, probably best option is to create SIMBL plugin that swizzles NSMenu.